# Implementing a graph with hash table

Tags: data-structures, hash, graph, hashtable, theory

I understand the "theory" behind it. Is some type or array of linked list where their position in the array is the result of doing "hashFuction(element) mod array.length" and you used the list to manage collisions.

My question is, what is actually the best length for the array? We are working with graph with max 20,000 nodes. But I think an array of 20,000 elements is already too inefficient.

I was thinking about creating an array with X length and then if it reaches that many elements do something like copy all element to an array of 2X, but the problem is that they would not have the same index for the elements and I can actually "copy" all the array, I would need to do for each element apply the  hash function to find their new place and would be very very slow if I am talking about a 10,000 elements array.

Sorry for my grammar mistakes, English is not my native language.

Comment: From what I understand, you are implementing something which uses a hash table to maintain ...? Could you elaborate? Do you have a link to a paper?

Comment: Yes, [here](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0908.3089.pdf). Is a implementation of graph, where we storage the nodes in the hash table.

Answer (score 0):

What you've described is essentially a chained hash table, and your question boils down to how to size that table so that it's space efficient. I think you're overengineering your solution. Instead, just use a standard, off-the-shelf implementation of a hash table in your Programming Language of Choice. It's likely to be much more optimized than whatever you'd come up with and would probably have many fewer bugs.

Hope this helps!